# Exercise about the size biased distribution

Tags: probability-theory

Can somebody help me with the following exercise:

> Let $\mathbf{P} \in \mathcal{M}_1\bigl([0,\infty)\bigr)$ with $m_\mathbf{P} := \int x \, \mathbf{P}(dx) \in (0,\infty)$, define a probability measure $\hat{\mathbf{P}}(A) \in \mathcal{M}_1\bigl([0,\infty)\bigr)$ by
>   \begin{equation*}
> \hat{\mathbf{P}}(A) := \frac{1}{m_\mathbf{P}} \int_A x \, \mathbf{P}(dx), \quad A \in \mathcal{B}\bigl([0,\infty)\bigr). 
> \end{equation*}
>   This is called the size-biased distribution corresponding to $\mathbf{P}$.
>
> Let $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ non-negative real random variables with $\mathbf{E}[X_i] = 1$ for all $i \in I$, $\mathbf{P}_i := \mathbf{P} \circ X_i^{-1}$.
>
> Show that
>   \begin{equation*}
> \{\hat{\mathbf{P}}_i : i \in I\} \text{ tight } \Longleftrightarrow \{X_i : i \in I\}  \text{ uniformly integrable.}
> \end{equation*}

I need the general idea of the proof or better a full proof (please don't use the "transfer theorem").

Yeah, yeah, "off-topic" & "lack of context" is ***constantly*** abused here.

So, please, here's my proof (that pretty much destroys any possibility to get a real answer):

"$\Longrightarrow$":

Assume that $\{\hat{\mathbf{P}}_i : i \in I\}$ are tight. This means that for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a compact set $K\in \mathcal{B}\bigl([0,\infty)\bigr)$, so that
\begin{equation*}
\sup \bigl\{ \hat{\mathbf{P}}_i\bigl[[0,\infty)\setminus K\bigr] : i \in I \bigr\} < \varepsilon \, .
\end{equation*}

Since $K$ is compact, there is an $a \in [0,\infty)$, so that $a > \sup(K)$. Obviously $0 \le \inf(K)$ also holds.

$m_{\mathbf{P}_i} = 1$ because $\mathbf{E}[X_i] = 1$. Also since $X_i$ is non-negative the value of the integral $\int_A X_i \, d\mathbf{P}$ is monotonic regarding $A$. Using these facts we get:
\begin{align*}
\varepsilon > \hat{\mathbf{P}}_i\bigl[[0,\infty)\setminus K\bigr)\bigr] = \int_{[0,\infty)\setminus K} x \, d\mathbf{P}_i = \int_{X_i^{-1}([0,\infty)\setminus K)} X_i \, d\mathbf{P} \ge  \int_{X_i^{-1}((a,\infty))} X_i \, d\mathbf{P} \, .
\end{align*}

Since for *any* $\varepsilon>0$ we can find such an $a \in [0, \infty)$ it must hold that:
\begin{equation*}
\inf_{a\in[0,\infty)} \sup_{i\in I} \int_{\{|X_i| > a\}} |X_i| \, d\mathbf{P} = 0 \, ,
\end{equation*}
or in other words, the $\{X_i : i\in I\}$ are uniformly integrable.

"$\Longleftarrow$":

Now conversely assume that $\{X_i : i\in I\}$ are uniformly integrable. This means that for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there is an $a\in [0, \infty)$ so that
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\{|X_i| > a\}} |X_i| \, d\mathbf{P} < \varepsilon \quad \text{ for all }i\in I \, .
\end{equation*}
The set $K:=[0, a] \subset [0, \infty)$ is compact. Then for any $i\in I$
\begin{align*}
\hat{\mathbf{P}}_i\bigl[[0, \infty)\setminus K\bigr] &= \hat{\mathbf{P}}_i\bigl[(a,\infty)\bigr] = \frac{1}{m_{\mathbf{P}_i}} \int_{(a,\infty)} x \, d \mathbf{P}_i \\ &= \frac{1}{m_{\mathbf{P}_i}} \int_{X_i^{-1}((a,\infty))} X_i \, d \mathbf{P}  = \int_{\{|X_i| > a\}} |X_i| \, d\mathbf{P} < \varepsilon \, ,
\end{align*} which means that the $\{\hat{\mathbf{P}}_i : i \in I\}$ are tight. $\square$

Comment: Just to check, what is $\mathcal{M}?$

Comment: @GeorgeS: $\mathcal{M}$ = radon measures, $\mathcal{M}_1$ = probability measures

Answer (score 1):

In this context, $m_{\mathbf P_i}=1$ and using the transfer theorem, we have for each $R$, 
$$\widehat{\mathbf P }_i\left(\mathbf R\setminus [-R,R]\right)=\mathbb E_{\mathbf P}\left[|X_i|\mathbf 1\{|X_i|\gt R\}  \right],$$
where $\mathbf 1(A)$ denotes the indicator function of the set $A$ and $\mathbb E_{\mathbf P}$ the expectation with respect to the probability measure $\mathbf P$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your notation. For example, what does the $\mathbf{1}$ mean or $\mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{P}}$?

Comment: Please see edit.